# GParted allocation trouble on Win8.1/Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: partitioning

After my old hard drive crashed, I decided to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 on my new drive (Windows was installed first, both with USB). Upon configuring Ubuntu, I partitioned about 698-ish Gb to Ubuntu and 232-ishGb to Windows.

As of then, partitions looked like this:

**/dev/sda1** | ntfs | System Reserved | 350Mb

**/dev/sda2** | ntfs | n/a | 232.54Gb

which are for Windows, and

**/dev/sda3** | extended | 698.63Gb

which is for Ubuntu.

Now **sda3** has subcategories, **sda5** through **sda6.** sda5 held 690.76Gb, and sda6, the linux-swap, held 7.87Gb. These are all formatted as ext4.

As of late I've wanted to repartition my drives to store 750Gb on Windows and 250Gb (or however much will actually fit after what the system needs is taken; it's a 1Tb drive) on Ubuntu. So, I booted up my laptop with the USB I installed Ubuntu on, selected "Try Ubuntu without installing" and opened up GParted to resize things.

I started by shrinking **sda5** to 250.00Gb, which worked perfectly. Then I had 440.76Gb of unallocated space, which I shifted to the left to it'd be next to **sda2** enabling to me to expand it, thus expand Windows. But since it was unallocated, I couldn't expand **sda2** into it in GParted or Windows Disk Management; I assigned a spot as **sda7,** but it required to have 1Mb of unallocated free space before it, which I couldn't remove...Analyzing that Mb of free space tells me its minimum size is 1Mb, but its maximum is 0Mb, and I can't change any values.

And I still can't expand **sda2.** Now, things look like this:

**/dev/sda1** | ntfs | 350Mb

**/dev/sda2** | 232.54Gb

**/dev/sda3** | extended | 698.63Gb

**>unallocated** | unallocated | 1Mb

**>/dev/sda7** | ext4 | 440.76Gb

**>/dev/sda5** | ext4 | 250Gb

**>/dev/sda6** | linux-swap | 7.87Gb

...Can anyone tell me what's going on? And if/how I can enlarge **sda2?**

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concern, you have shrunk sda5, not sda3, so the allocated space (before creating sda7) is still inside sda3, and after being created, sda7 is inside sda3.

I suggest you delete sda7, shrink sda3 from the left, then you can enlarge sda2.

Comment: Thank you! That's my problem though: I can't shrink sda3 because it's an "extended" file system that has sda5-7 in subcategories. I can't get any of its subs out of it either :(

Comment: You can delete sda7 and shrink sda3 with gparted, and then as rancho suggest, enlarge Windows partition sda2 with Windows' bundled tool: Disk Management.

Comment: Well, sda3 seems like it's a "folder" under which sda7, 5, and 6 are located. I can't do anything to it :(

Comment: Oh, I think I just got it by turning SwapOff in the linux-swap partition. I tried that earlier. Thank you for your help! :D

Comment: Well I'm just pretty much a newbie anyway :P Oh and sorry that I forgot to mention that it's necessary to unmount all logical partitions, and swapoff swap partition inside an extended partition, in order to unmount that extended partition before performing any modification.

Answer (score 0):

In gparted first reduce your sda 7 and then select the whole sda3 and reduce it.

Then go to Windows and expand sda2 to the newly created unallocated disk space

GOLDEN RULE: Never ever touch your windows partition with gparted. Always use disk management of windows.

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to do anything to sda3 though, because of its "extended" file system. I can't do anything expect check its properties and manage flags.